# Is it possible to speed up loading multiple files in python with multithreading?

Tags: python

Consider the task of reading in 10000 files, each of which is a text file containing a single integer, and summing up the numbers as quickly as possible.

Clearly, this will be an I/O bound task. As far as I am aware, an I/O bound task is a good candidate for multithreading in Python in order to improve performance. While no more than one CPU core will be used due to the GIL, multithreading would in theory allow the program to issue many parallel disk read requests, speeding up the execution of the program as the GIL is released during I/O blocking operations.

The following code does this task with both single threaded and multi threaded methods. The multi threaded method batches the filenames into batches of 100 and submits the batches to a thread pool executor.

```py
import concurrent.futures
import tempfile
import os
import time

def single_threaded_test():
    filenames = os.listdir(temp_dir.name)
    total = 0
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(os.path.join(temp_dir.name, filename)) as f:
            total += int(f.read())
    print('Total:', total)

def multi_threaded_test():
    filenames = os.listdir(temp_dir.name)

    def batch_list(l, n):
        for i in range(0, len(l), n):
            yield l[i:i + n]

    def process_filenames(batch_filenames):
        subtotal = 0
        for filename in batch_filenames:
            with open(os.path.join(temp_dir.name, filename)) as f:
                subtotal += int(f.read())
        return subtotal

    # Submit to the Thread Pool in batches of 100 filenames
    filename_batches = batch_list(filenames, 100)

    total = 0
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for future in executor.map(process_filenames, filename_batches):
            total += future
    print('Total:', total)

print('Writing files...')

temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
for i in range(10000):
    with open(os.path.join(temp_dir.name, f'{i}.txt'), 'wt') as f:
        f.write(str(i))


print('Testing single threaded:')

t = time.process_time()

single_threaded_test()

elapsed_time_st = time.process_time() - t

print('Elapsed time:', elapsed_time_st)

print('Testing multi threaded:')

t = time.process_time()

multi_threaded_test()

elapsed_time_mt = time.process_time() - t

print('Elapsed time:', elapsed_time_mt)
```

Surprisingly, on my machine, the multi-threaded code was almost 2x slower at 1.78 seconds vs 0.94 seconds for single-threaded.

Can anyone explain why the multi-threaded method is not faster?

Comment: Without even looking at your code, I can say you kinda alluded to the problem already -- it's I/O-bound.  Now, the thing with I/O (particularly with disks) is that because it deals with slower hardware, you tend to also have clever algorithms built into the operating system / drivers to do caching and scheduling when serving multiple requests.  There is often hardware-level caching too.  If you spawn a bunch of threads and hammer the I/O scheduler and cache, it's gonna try to give everyone a fair chance, and you'll likely lose performance benefits that a single client might enjoy.

Comment: Though I had not personally experimented with it or seen any hard benchmark numbers, I had read that parallel code handling the same hard disk cannot be faster than serial code because the disk itself can only do one thing at a time, and multiple threads will force the disk to jump around and ruin potential speedups from disk caching. In short, the rule of thumb was multiple disks for parallel IO just like multiple CPUs for parallel computing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that I was using `time.process_time()` to measure performance.
If I use `time.time()` instead, multi threading is indeed significantly faster.